# Template literals not working correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am use the .map method to return the name of an object, and ultimately populate the innerHTML of a table with that name.

The problem is I can't get it to show the appropriate values.

So for example, for the flavor Almond_Divinity it would have a Table row with three table data tags.  The first  would have the name 'Almond Divinity,' the second  would have the price '.99', and the third  would have the link.

My javascript is below:

```
    var Menu = {
    Almond_Divinity : {name: 'Almond Divinity', price: .99, history: 'x', availability: 'x'},
    Mango_Sorbet : {name: 'Mango Sorbet', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Decaf : {name: 'Decaf', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Almond_Chocolate_Coconut : {name: 'Almond Chocolate Coconut', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Alpine_Fudge_Crunch : {name: 'Alpine Fudge Crunch', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Banana_Cream_Pie : {name: 'Banana Cream Pie', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Birthday_Cake : {name: 'Birthday Cake:', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Black_Raspberry_Chocolate_Crunch : {name: 'Black Raspberry Chocolate Crunch', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Blueberry_Cobbler : {name: 'Blueberry Cobbler', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Black_Walnut : {name: 'Black Walnut', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Mint_Chocolate_Chip : {name: 'Mint Chocolate Chip', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Caramel_Apple : {name: 'Caramel Apple:', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Almond_Divinity : {name: 'Almond Divinity', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Cherries_Jubilee : {name: 'Cherries Jubilee', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Tutti_Frutti : {name: 'Tutti Frutti', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Artic_Roll : {name: 'Artic Roll', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Dame_Blanche : {name: 'Dame Blanche', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Sizzling_Brownie : {name: 'Sizzling Brownie', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''},
    Choco_Taco : {name: 'Choco-Taco', price: .99, history: '', availability: ''}

};

window.onload = function () {
  // calls the keys property of the Object to find Menu and it's associated properties, and then uses the sort method to compare them and sort them alphabetically
  const sortedFlavors = Object.keys(Menu).sort(function(a, b) {return - (name[a] - name[b])});

  document.querySelector('#icecream_flavors').innerHTML = sortedFlavors.map(function icecream_flavor(currentValue, index, array) { return '<td>${currentValue}</td><td>$.99</td><td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a></td>'}).join('')
};
```

And my HTML is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Betty's icecream</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/logo.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/small.css" media="(max-width: 479px)" title="no title"> -->
  <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
  @font-face {
    font-family: "KR Sweet Tooth";
    src: url("fonts/KR Sweet Tooth.ttf");
  }
  </style>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <nav class="minus-padding">
    <div class="align-left">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-li-left"><a href=""> Home </a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-left">Menu <a href=""></a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-left">Contact <a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="align-right">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-li-right">Parties</li>
        <li class="nav-li-right">Cakes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav> -->
  <nav id="nav" class="minus-padding">
    <div class="align-left">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-li-left"><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-left"><a href="#menu"> Menu </a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-left"><a href="#employees">Employees</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-left"><a href="" onclick="newWindow()">View Mobile</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-left"><a id="demo" href="#" >Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <img srcset="images/food-restaurant-fruits-orange.jpg  1280w"
    sizes="(min-width: 36em) 100vw,
    100vw"
    src="images/food-restaurant-fruits-orange.jpg"
    alt="A Banana Split" />
  </div>
    <div class="home">
      <h1>
        Betty's <br> <p id="logo"> s </p> Parlor
      </h1>
    </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column-left">
      <div class="address">
        <p class="sidebar" id="sidebar-title">
          550 Ice Cream Lane
          Mulberry Hollow,
          Utah
          84501
          <br>
          <br>
          208-208-2080
        </p>
        <div class="address">
          <p class="sidebar">
            Put a bird on it 3 wolf moon street art synth, lumbersexual slow-carb poke live-edge brooklyn coloring book tattooed pour-over kombucha. Pitchfork sartorial marfa, tote bag pop-up hell of 90's lo-fi vape coloring book distillery fap fixie. Edison bulb chicharrones actually fanny pack, normcore salvia microdosing fixie activated charcoal direct trade food truck 3 wolf moon. Knausgaard chia copper mug cred, deep v roof party PBR&B kombucha semiotics pickled poutine man bun messenger bag. Shoreditch tbh intelligentsia hammock master cleanse banjo. Wayfarers pork belly skateboard freegan, leggings migas iPhone VHS photo booth knausgaard truffaut. Coloring book forage
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="column-right fl-scroll-link">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th id="header-modified">Flavor
          </th>
          <th>Price
          </th>
          <th>
            link
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="icecream_flavors">

        </tr>
        <!-- <tr>
          <td>
            Almond Divinity
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Almond Chocolate Coconut
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Alpine Fudge Crunch
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Banana Cream Pie
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Birthday Cake
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Decaf
          </td>
          <td>$.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Black Raspberry Chocolate Crunch
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Blueberry Cobbler
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Black Walnut
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Mint Chocolate Chip
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Caramel Apple
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Almond Divinity
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Almond Chocolate Coconut
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Alpine Fudge Crunch
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Banana Cream Pie
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Birthday Cake
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Decaf
          </td>
          <td>$.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Black Raspberry Chocolate Crunch
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Blueberry Cobbler
          </td>
          <td>
            $.99
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a>
          </td>
        </tr> -->
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="empty">

      <div class="row">
        <h2 id="employees">Employees</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 10px">

    </div>

    <div class="row-full">
      <div class="center">
        <!-- grids  -->
        <div class="grid">
          <img class="circle" src="images/bow-tie-businessman-fashion-man.jpg" alt="boss image" />
          <a href="#"><p>Meet Ben: An impulsive Vanilla lover.</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
          <img class="circle" src="images/man-couple-people-woman.jpg" alt="coworkers boxing" />
          <a href="#"><p>Meet Dolley Madison: An argumentative mint chocolate-chipper. </p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
          <img class="circle" src="images/pexels-photo (1).jpg" alt="man lifting weights" />
          <a href="#"><p>Meet Jerry: A strawberry introvert. </p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
          <img class="circle" src="images/pexels-photo-89524 (1).jpg" alt="little girl" />
          <a href="#"><p>Meet Robert Green: A flirtatious chocolate lover. </p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
          <img class="circle" src="images/pexels-photo-127968.jpg" alt="little girl floating" />
          <a href="#"><p>Meet Nicholas Lemery: A sherbet pessimist. </p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
          <img class="circle" src="images/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="little girl surprised"/>
          <a href="#"><p>Meet H. Glasse: An aggressive Rocky Roader. </p></a>
        </div>


        <footer class="footer">
          <div class="footer-row">
            <ul id="footer-ul">
              <li class="footer-li"><a href="">Franchise</a></li>
              <li class="footer-li"><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
              <li class="footer-li"><a href="">Inquiries</a></li>
              <li class="footer-li"><a href="">Parties</a></li>
              <li class="footer-li"><a href="">Adventure</a></li>
              <li class="footer-li"><a href="">Coupons</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <p class="footer-p">
              copyright © Trrapp
            </p>
          </div>
        </footer>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  </body>
  <script src="src/menu.js"
  <script>
  // Select all links with hashes
  $('a[href*="#"]')
    // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function(event) {
      // On-page links
      if (
        location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
        &&
        location.hostname == this.hostname
      ) {
        // Figure out element to scroll to
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        // Does a scroll target exist?
        if (target.length) {
          // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000, function() {
            // Callback after animation
            // Must change focus!
            var $target = $(target);
            $target.focus();
            if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
              return false;
            } else {
              $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
              $target.focus(); // Set focus again
            };
          });
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function newWindow() {
      newwindow = window.open('https://trrapp12.github.io/ice-cream/', '', 'width=680,height=680')

      function resizeWinTo() {
        newwindow.resizeTo(20, 20);
        newwindow.focus();
        alert("inner function called")
      };
      resizeWinTo();
    };

  </script>
</html>
```

The result I am getting is this:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLH1V.jpg)

Any help you can give would be appreciated.  And since I'm making no claims to greatness here, condescending commentary need not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the string in backticks to get string interpolated:

```
sortedFlavors.map(function(currentValue) {
  return `<td>${currentValue}</td><td>$.99</td><td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a></td>`
}).join('')
```

Also, for sure, the items won't be sorted as a subtraction operation on strings results in `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of single quotes `'`

```
//notice that ' is replaced with `

  document.querySelector('#icecream_flavors').innerHTML =   
        sortedFlavors.map( function icecream_flavor(currentValue, index, array) { 
            return `<td>${currentValue}</td><td>$.99</td><td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream">History</a></td>`
   }).join('');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Really appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

```
<table id="icecream_flavors"></table>    
 $(document).ready(function(){

            var temp="";
            for(var prop in Menu){
            temp+="<tr><td>"+Menu[prop].name+"</td><td>"+Menu[prop].price+"</td><td>"+Menu[prop].availability+"</td></tr>";
            }
            $("#icecream_flavors").append(temp);


            });
```